# Removing Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x64)

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to remove the Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x64). It says it's uninstalled when I try to remove it from `Control Panel->Programs and Features`, but the list item is still there, and if I try to remove it again, it brings up the prompt to install it.

How do I get rid of this program completely, or how can i install it correctly, because when I install Visual studio 2012 Ultimate, I get an error with this title "Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x64) package failed"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are ok with just removing it from the add/remove list, you can delete the appropriate subkey, based on the value of the DisplayName, from this registry key:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

If you are running a 64bit version of windows you can also check this registry key as well

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

This is based on information from the Microsoft [kb314481](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314481). It was written for XP SP3, but still applies to later versions of Windows.